# Passing data from a StatelessWidget to a StatefulWidget

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am very new to flutter and I am trying to create a Generic Button widget that I can just pass parameters into (Text, color, etc.) keeping it short to just text right now. So I have setup my main app named `SplashScreen` and in the `body` I add the `GenericButton` class. I would like to know if there is a way for me to pass a string of text or any other kind of data, save that in my `GenericButton` class so that I can push that into my `_GenericButtonState` using `widget.buttonText`

```
final String _title = "Flutter Demo";
// * This is the landing page
class SplashScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  // * This widget is the root of your application.
  const SplashScreen({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: _title,
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.deepPurple,
        ),
        home: Scaffold
          (
          appBar: AppBar
            (
              title: Text(_title)
          ),
          body: GenericButton() // <-- Statelful Widget I would like to pass data into.
        )
    );
  }
}

// * Creating reusable button
class GenericButton extends StatefulWidget
{
    final String buttonText;
    const GenericButton(this.buttonText);

    @override
    _GenericButtonState createState() => _GenericButtonState();
}

class _GenericButtonState extends State<GenericButton>
{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) 
  {
    return OutlinedButton(
      child: Text(widget.buttonText),
      onPressed: ()
      {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LocationsPage()),
        );
      }, 
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do that normally through constructor , this is working example from one of my projects

```
class PrimaryButton extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final Color color;
  final Color textColor;
  final Function onTap;
  final EdgeInsets edgeInsets;
  final bool pending;

  const PrimaryButton({
    Key key,
    @required this.text,
    @required this.onTap,
    this.color = AppTheme.primaryColor,
    this.textColor = AppTheme.secondaryColor,
    this.edgeInsets = const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4.0, horizontal: 16.0),
    this.pending = false,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap:  pending ? null: onTap,
      child: Container(
        child: Center(
          child: pending
              ? Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                  child: SpinKitThreeBounce(
                    color: AppTheme.scaffoldBackgroundColor,
                    size: 15.0,
                  ),
                )
              : Text(
                  text,
                  style: AppTheme.textTheme.headline5.copyWith(fontSize: 18.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,color: textColor),
                ),
        ),
        margin: edgeInsets,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
        width: double.infinity,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(color: color, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0)),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Is AppTheme.primaryColor a deprecated call? I'm on flutter 2.0.5 and all I have access to is AppBarTheme

Comment: no , sorry this is my own class in separate file , for you you can do 
Theme.of(context).primaryColor

Comment: and if your problem solved give the answer upvote ;)

Answer (score 0):

You have already defined the buttonText parameter. You have to pass a text into it (like the _title), and anytime you want a new text pass that as the new parameter.

Your GenericButton is a StatefulWidget, if the buttonText parameter changes, the widget won't redraw itself. The **didChangeDependencies** method will be fired and you need to handle the changes manually: update any state inside the _GenericButtonState

**But:**
If you change the GenericButton to StatelessWidget, any time the buttonText parameter changes the widget will redraw itself.

**Conclusion**:
As I understood what you want to build, you'd better have a GenericButton StatelessWidget with the parameters and pass them from the parent, which could be the StatefulWidget as that will manage the state of the texts and other arguments.

You can read more about state management here: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options